# How to solve wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to install swift on ubunu 18.04.
I tried to install it with the command `sudo snap install swift` but when i try to start it by typing `swift` i get the error `/snap/swift/5/bin/swift: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`.
What can i do for solve this error?

my `arch` is `x86_64`

my `uname -m` is `x86_64`

Comment: What CPU architecture of your Ubuntu? Please add output of `arch` and `uname -m` to the question.

Comment: i've updated the question with the infos that you asked

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are problems with this snap, its maintainer forgot to add the `libatomic.so.1` with correct bitness and CPU architecture:

> ```
> $ snap run --shell swift
> $ ldd /snap/swift/5/bin/swift | grep not
>   libatomic.so.1 => not found
> ```
>
> ```
> $ cd /snap/swift/current $ find -name libatomic.so*
> ./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1
> ./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.1.0
> ./usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/libatomic.so
> ```

The solution would be to use `edge` channel for this snap:

```
snap install swift --edge
```

Comment: i've tried but didn't work, it still gives the same error

Comment: The problem is inside the snap, so we should not install libatomic1 on "host" system. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libatomic1 by `sudo apt install libatomic1`

Comment: i've tried but didn't work, it still gives the same error

Comment: The swift package has its own libatomic.so packages in a read-only filesystem and it is a standalone package with non-classic confinement, so it can't execute any files that are installed by libatomic1.