# error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: 19.10, shared-library, visual-studio-code

I tried to program in swift but somehow I **can't build** my code.
I am using **VSCode** . I read that you have to install sourcekit-lsp, but I am unsure if I installed it correctly.

Then I did the following command to check the version:

```
$ swift -version
/snap/swift/5/bin/swift: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

but as you can see, there is something wrong with libatomic.so.1.

I then tried to install libatomic library but it is already installed.

I also tried the answers in this post -> [How to solve wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142360/how-to-solve-wrong-elf-class-elfclass32/1192080?noredirect=1#comment1995063_1192080)

,but that didn't solve the problem neither.

**What do I have to do to be able to code in swift in VSCode?**

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang libpython-dev libblocksruntime-dev
```

I had the same error setting up [swift-tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md) (CPU only)

https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md